# How to get other's comments to my post through facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get who commented or liked to my post on Facebook through facebook api.
I used Facebook Graph API and could get post_id. 
And used this endpoint: {POST_ID}/comments, but it returned only my comments.
Is there any way to get other's comments with user id?

Comment: I think you can only get those for users that have also logged in to your app, and granted it access to their basic info at least.